# fetching data from angular controller and display it on the html view got error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, video

I am developing an online course application and I am trying to display the course details of a course along with video lectures which are on youtube. 
My angular controller is fetching the course details from the node.js controller and displaying it on the html view, however it doesn't show get the youtube video link. Its because I changed the mongoose schema for storing course video from a String to String Array. If I keep the mongoose schema for course video as String, then I can view the video.

Here is the mongoose schema, file name is course.server.model.js

```
'use strict';

/**
* Module dependencies
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
* Course Schema
*/
var CourseSchema = new Schema({
created: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now
},
title: {
type: String,
default: '',
trim: true,
required: 'Title cannot be blank'
},
content: {
type: String,
default: '',
trim: true
},
courseLecture: [{
week_number: { type: Number },
lecture_video: [String]
}],
user: {
type: Schema.ObjectId,
ref: 'User'
}
});

mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

In the schema, I have kept lecture_video as String array within courseLecture.

Here is my angular controller. controller name is courses.client.controller.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('courses')
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://www.youtube.com/**'
  ]);
})
.controller('CoursesController', CoursesController);

CoursesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'courseResolve', 'Authentication'];

function CoursesController($scope, course, Authentication) {
var vm = this;

vm.course = course;
vm.authentication = Authentication;

$scope.product = {
  name: 'some name',
  description: 'some description',
  media: [{
    src: vm.course.courseLecture.lecture_video
  }]
};

console.log('value of courseLecture: ' + vm.course);

console.log('value of youtube embed lecture is: ' + vm.course.courseLecture.lecture_video);

$scope.getIframeSrc = function(src) {
  return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + src;
};
}
}());
```

If I do console.log for vm.course.courseLecture.lecture_video then I get undefined. However, I do get undefined for it, even from node.js controller as well.

Here is my html view. file name :- view-course.client.view.html

```
<style>
.video-container {
height: 400px;
width: 200px;
}
.thumbnail1 {
height: 450px;
width: 220px;
}
</style>
<section>
<div class="page-header">
<h1 ng-bind="vm.course.title"></h1>
</div>
<small>
<em class="text-muted">
  Posted on
  <span ng-bind="vm.course.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span>
  by
  <span ng-if="vm.course.user" ng-bind="vm.course.user.displayName"></span>
  <span ng-if="!vm.course.user">Deleted User</span>
</em>
</small>
<p class="lead" ng-bind="vm.course.content"></p>
<div ng-repeat="media in product.media">
<div class="thumbnail1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media.src)}}" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Right now with this, I can see the course details using REST calls, only the video link doesn't work, which starts working if in the course schema, in the courseLecture property, if I change the lecture_video from lecture_video: [String] to lecture_video: {type:String}.
I can view the video. I want to store all the video links for a week in an array so the all the videos can be displayed. 
Please help me with what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got data according to your schema then your angular controller can be like bellow to add each *video url* in `media`.  because your `courseLecture` is an array and in `courseLecture` the `lecture_video` also an array so need to iterate as  `media` array so need two `forEach` or `for` loop.

```
$scope.product = {
    name: 'some name',
    description: 'some description',
    media: []
  };

  (vm.course.courseLecture).forEach(function(lecture) {
    (lecture.lecture_video).forEach(function(videoUrl) {
      $scope.product.media.push({src: videoUrl});
    });
  });
```

and Html

```
<div ng-repeat="media in product.media">
    <div class="thumbnail1 col-xs-12 col-sm-9" >
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media.src)}}" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: With this, I'm not getting the other details as well on the page now, like course title, course content. I'm getting a blank page now.

Comment: but why I did not change your other code without  `media`. others code should be working if previous was working well. I have shown only what should for media @VikasPandey

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I'm not talking about product.name or product.description values. They are just dummy's. I'm talking about the course content I am getting from mongodb. That content is not getting displayed now.  I think in this line, $scope.product.push({src: videoUrl}); , it should be modified to $scope.product.push({src: videoUrl}, media);  then it should work . I didn't tested though. @shaishab-roy

Comment: can you show me your actual data that come from mongodb? @VikasPandey

Comment: right now i'm getting, TypeError: $scope.product.push is not a function. At both the forEach loop.  at http://localhost:3000/modules/courses/client/controllers/courses.client.controller.js:51:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/modules/courses/client/controllers/courses.client.controller.js:50:31    @shaishab-roy

Comment: sorry it was mistake should be `$scope.product.media.push` @VikasPandey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133783/discussion-between-vikas-pandey-and-shaishab-roy).

Comment: now I can see the video.
Thanks for your help
one quick question, when I'm trying to add new videos then it doesn't update the mongodb

Comment: Hey sorry for the update, but this doesn't seems to be showing all the video in the html view. It only shows one video, even though I have two video url in the lecture_video now

Comment: should be working can see this link https://plnkr.co/edit/EY5iE10J43pvvtGsOGGQ?p=preview

Comment: Can you look at this question, I posted today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818146/isauthenticated-function-not-working-node-js-passport . @shaishab-roy

Answer (score 0):

Since the type has changed, there will be inconsistency in the data that is coming from rest. Hence, You have to provide backward compatibility for the string url as well as the array of string urls.

For string urls :

```
<div ng-if="isString(product.media)">
<div class="thumbnail1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe ng-src="getIframeSrc(product.media.src)" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For Array of string url :

```
<div ng-if="!isString(product.media)">
    <div ng-repeat="media in product.media">
    <div class="thumbnail1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media.src)}}" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In controller :

```
$scope.isString = function(media){
    if(Array.isArray(media)){
        return false;//returns if it is an string
    }
    else{
        return true; // return if it is an array
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't play video. There is no difference in the result. I think, I need one more loop for media, since video_lecture is also an array.  @bala-abhinav

Comment: Sure, This was just to give an example of what i said. I would suggest you to change it accordingly to your data model..

Answer (score 0):

`vm.course.courseLecture[0].lecture_video` is an array which has an array of videos in the schema. In client you create `$scope.product` with `media` key which has an array value, inside is a object again with key `src` which should have the value `vm.course.courseLecture[0].lecture_video`. `product.media.src[0]` is the key you want to iterate.

```
<div ng-repeat="media in product.media.src[0]">
<div class="thumbnail1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media)}}" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```